# Properties of Lebesgue integrable functions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Can anyone help me to prove the following:

If $f$ and $g$ are in $\mathfrak{L}(\mu )$ on $E$, then prove the following: 
(i) If $a\leq f(x)\leq b$ for $x\in E$, and if $\mu \left(E\right)<\infty $, then 
        $a\mu(E) \le \int_E f d\mu \le b \mu(E) $
(ii) If $f(x)\le g(x)$ for $x\in E$, then $\int_E f d\mu \le \int_E g d\mu$.

I have referred to "Walter Rudin Principles of Mathematical analysis Page number 315".

For $(ii)$ I have the following proof:
 Let $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for $x \in E$. Then $f^+ = \text{max}(f,0) \leq \text{max}(g, 0) = g^+$ and $f^- = -\text{min}(f, 0) \geq -\text{min}(g, 0) = g^-$ (by definition) ($\because~ \text{min}(f, 0) \leq \text{min}(g, 0)$).

''$\therefore~ \int\limits_E f^+ d \mu \leq \int\limits_E g^+ d\mu$ and $\int\limits_E f^- d \mu \geq \int\limits_Eg^- d\mu$ (by definition)''

\textbf{The above step is not cleared to me}

Hence $\int\limits_E f d \mu = \int\limits_E f^+ d\mu -  \int\limits_E f^- d\mu \leq \int\limits_E g^+ d\mu - \int\limits_E g^- d \mu = \int\limits_E g d\mu$

Thus $\int\limits_E f d \mu \leq \int\limits_E g d\mu.$

Please provide me elaborated proofs for $(i)$ and $(ii)$. Thank you

Comment: Can you explain what of "the above step" you do understand and what you do not?

Comment: The step is highlighted in an inverted comma. I could not understand how to prove that by definition.

Comment: It is given as remark in Rudin (Page 315)

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what I am not allowed to use here...

If $f,g$ are integrable then so is $h=g-f $

If $h \ge 0$ on $E$, then $\int_E h \ge 0$.

Since $\int_E g = \int_E f + \int_E h$ we see that $ \int_E g \ge \int_E f$.

The first result follows noting that $\int_E a d \mu = a \mu(E)$ and similarly
for $b$.